# Postgres 'psql' command is not working in ubuntu

Tags: psql

I am new to psql. In terminal. I entered the following command

```
psql -U postgres
```

I am facing the following error:

> psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
>       Is the server running locally and accepting
>       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Someone please help me in this regard.

Comment: Well... Is the server running? Check the output of ``ps -elf``.

Comment: yes,Server is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, post here related messages from: **/postgres/server.log** and **psql --version**.

If inside server.log something like this, read next.

> FATAL:  pre-existing shared memory block (key 5432001, ID 65538) is
>   still in use  **HINT:**  If you're sure there are no old server processes
>   still running, remove the shared memory block or just **delete the file
>   "postmaster.pid".**

If you haven't a critical data in your postrgres, you could immediately try this fix:

1. `/etc/init.d/postgresql stop` (if some processes running, try a peaceful shutdown)
2. `rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid` (use the HINT, delete it)
3. `/etc/init.d/postgresql start` (check it).